# How to have two timeline feeds for two separate groups and query separately

Tags: getstream-io

I'm trying to understand how [Stream](https://getstream.io/) works, but I just don't get it... I have two feeds I want to create, they should be seperate from each other.

With the example below I thought that I'm first adding activities as Eric, I have one activity that goes just to Eric's feed, one that goes to the **cpaentries** feed and one that goes to the **productcafe** feed.

```
const ericToken = client.feed('timeline', 'eric').token
var ericFeed = client.feed('timeline', 'eric', ericToken);

// Add the activity to the feed
ericFeed.addActivity({
    actor: 'eric',
    tweet: 'Hello world',
    verb: 'tweet',
    object: 1
});


ericFeed.addActivity({
    actor: 'eric',
    tweet: 'Hello world, CPA EntriesNew',
    verb: 'tweet',
    object: 1,
    to: ['timeline:cpaentries']
});

ericFeed.addActivity({
    actor: 'eric',
    tweet: 'Hello world, Product CafeNew',
    verb: 'tweet',
    object: 1,
    to: ['timeline:productcafe']
});
```

Now I am trying to ONLY retrieve the timeline containing **cpaentries** activities. Think of this as the main feed every user should see when they open the app. I'm just generally confused about `client.feed`, the `to` field and following as well I suppose.

```
const cpaToken = client.feed('timeline', 'cpaentries').token
var cpaFeed = client.feed('timeline', 'cpaentries', cpaToken);


cpaFeed.get({limit:5}).then(function(body) {
    console.log(body);
    /* on success */
    }).catch(function(reason) {
    console.log(reason);
    /* on failure, reason.error contains an explanation */
});
```

This snippet basically just shows all posts, not only the **cpaentries** posts as I was hoping it would do.

Here's the body of my result:

```
{ results:
   [ { actor: 'eric',
       foreign_id: '',
       id: 'd2435d01-21bb-11e8-81f8-128899f22c76',
       object: '1',
       origin: null,
       target: '',
       time: '2018-03-07T03:58:40.503118',
       tweet: 'Hello world, CPA EntriesNew',
       verb: 'tweet' },
     { actor: 'eric',
       foreign_id: '',
       id: '83eb9b0e-21bb-11e8-a2ca-0a51ae8e7f7a',
       object: '1',
       origin: null,
       target: '',
       time: '2018-03-07T03:56:29.065704',
       tweet: 'Hello world, CPA EntriesNew',
       verb: 'tweet' },
     { actor: 'eric',
       foreign_id: '',
       id: 'fc9b804e-2154-11e8-b02a-128899f22c76',
       object: '1',
       origin: null,
       target: '',
       time: '2018-03-06T15:42:33.381897',
       tweet: 'Hello halli hallo world, CPA Entries',
       verb: 'tweet' },
     { actor: 'eric',
       foreign_id: '',
       id: '3602f521-2152-11e8-853b-0a51ae8e7f7a',
       object: '1',
       origin: null,
       target: '',
       time: '2018-03-06T15:22:41.199850',
       tweet: 'Hello world, CPA EntriesNew',
       verb: 'tweet' },
     { actor: 'eric',
       foreign_id: '',
       id: '281b133f-2152-11e8-8533-0a51ae8e7f7a',
       object: '1',
       origin: null,
       target: '',
       time: '2018-03-06T15:22:17.869808',
       tweet: 'Hello world, CPA EntriesNew',
       verb: 'tweet' } ],
}
```

Comment: can you include the content of `body` from the cpaFeed.get call to the question?

Comment: two followup questions - 

is this code running in the browser or server-side? (If it's running server-side, you don't need the `ericToken` variable - `client.feed('timeline', 'eric')` will work just fine.

is the `timeline:eric` feed "following" the `timeline:cpaentries` feed or the `timeline:productcafe` feed?

Answer (score 0):

> With the example below I thought that I'm first adding activities as Eric, I have one activity that goes just to Eric's feed, one that goes to the cpaentries feed and one that goes to the productcafe feed.

That's almost correct. In your example, **all** activities will go into Eric's feed. The second activity will go into Eric's feed, and be copied to the `cpaentries` feed. The third activity will go into Eric's feed, and be copied to the `productcafe` feed.

You can think of the `to` param as a collection of feeds to which the activity will be copied.

To get the behavior you thought would happen, the second and third activities would be added directly to the `cpaentries` and `productcafe` feeds respectively, with no `to` param. E.g.:

```
const cpaentriesFeed = client.feed('timeline', 'cpaentries', cpaentriesToken);

cpaentriesFeed.addActivity({
    actor: 'eric',
    tweet: 'Hello world, CPA EntriesNew',
    verb: 'tweet',
    object: 1
});

const productcafeFeed = client.feed('timeline', 'productcafe', productcafeToken);

productcafeFeed.addActivity({
    actor: 'eric',
    tweet: 'Hello world, Product CafeNew',
    verb: 'tweet',
    object: 1
});
```